# мозг в местном/предложном падеже

Tags: грамматика, падежи, существительные

Как правильно - **в головном мозгу** или **в головном мозге**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это зависит от смысла того, что вы хотите сказать.

Если речь идёт о мыслях, то нужно использовать местный падеж:

> В моём мозгу крутилась мысль о сдаче в плен.
>
> В моём мозгу я уже раздевал любимую.

Использование предложного падежа здесь неправильно.

Если речь идёт в химическом составе мозга, нейронах, либо о пользе/вреде мозга, то используется предложный падеж.

> В костном мозге содержится много железа.
>
> В большом мозге много пользы для выживания биологического вида.

---

> В твоём мозге много атомов = Your brain consists of a lot of atoms
>
> В твоём мозгу много атомов = You are thinking/dreaming about a lot of atoms

Поскольку "головной мозг" - это устойчивое словосочетание, обозначающее биологический орган, оно обычно используется в предложном падеже.

Comment: Иными словами, если речь идёт о мозге, как о физическом явлении, то используется предложный падеж. Ежели, как ум, сознание, то местный.